# Handling Floating Point Number in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, printing, bc

Can someone assist with my handling this calculation that I need in bash?

Currently I have the following:

```
Size=$((IPS * DataPages / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) * 1.05))
```

But I get the following error when trying to execute:

```
./buffer: line 20: IPS * DataPages / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) * 1.05: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".05")
```

I'm open to using other alternatives, like either print or awk or even bc, but I need some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` does not support floating point arithmetic. Use `bc` for that. To enabled floating point arithmetic in `bc` pass the `--mathlib` (or `-l`) option:

```
IPS=2
DataPages=3
bc --mathlib <<< "($IPS * $DataPages / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) * 1.05)"
```

To capture that into a shell variable use process substitution:

```
...
Size=$(bc --mathlib <<< "($IPS * $DataPages / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) * 1.05)")
```

Answer (score 1):

`(( ))` doesn't support floating point arithmetic. Use bc or awk.

**using bc**

```
Size=$( echo "scale=2; $IPS * $DataPages / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) * 1.05 " | bc ) 
# scale is for number of digits after the floating point
```

**using awk**

```
Size=$( awk -v ips="$IPS" -v dp="$DataPages" 'BEGIN{size=ips * dp/ (1024 * 1024 * 1024) * 1.05; printf "%0.02f",size}' )
```